# Magento Widget on CMS Block/Page?

Tags: magento, magento-1.5

I'm using an older version of Magento CE (1.5.0.1) and I'm trying to add a category URL to a CMS static block.  I found numerous posts stating that the way to do this is to use the {{widget ...}} directive, as so:

```
{{widget type="catalog/category_widget_link" anchor_text="Foo" title="My Category" template="catalog/category/widget/link/link_inline.phtml" id_path="category/33"}}
```

When I put this on a CMS block that is added to my header, what I get is the above, output as text.  It's not translating it.  I dug in further, and from what I can tell, it isn't designed to work.  A CMS Block creates an instance of the block template processor by calling `getBlockTemplateProcessor` in the CMS helper.  This is hard coded in the CMS modules `config.xml` to return an instance of `Mage_Cms_Model_Template_Filter`, which extends `Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template_Filter`.  If you dig into that, there's no `widgetDirective` method, which would be required for it to properly translate widget directives.  Unless I'm mistaken, CMS pages aren't designed to support widgets.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Do you have an "Insert Widget" button over the WYSIWYG?

Comment: Yes, and that's what it inserts.

Answer (score 0):

In CMS block, type as follows.

```
{{store direct_url='category1.html'}}
```

Where `category1.html` is URL of particular category

Comment: That's actually what I ended up doing.  I'm not so much in search of a solution as I am in search of an answer as to whether or not this *should* work.  Other answers I found have the {{widget...}} directive, and comments from the OP indicate it worked for them, so I'm confused...